# Input Validation on a textbox receiving Month

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a textbox on my form where a user must fill in a month, i figured out how to input numeric values but I'd like my textbox to receive numeric values between 1 and 12. I've already tried the min, max but none of them worked.

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Month" id="Month"onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"maxlength="2"placeholder="MM"required="required">
```

JavaScript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function isNumber(evt) {
evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false; 
}
return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I recommend to use autoNumeric plugin : http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/

Answer (score 1):

You should forego the extra JS and instead use `<input type="number">` and the `min`/`max` attributes:

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="Month" id="Month" min="1" max="12" placeholder="MM" required>
```

Comment: I can type 23 in this input, which is not valid

Comment: The big red box that appears around the input when you do tells you that the form is not filled out correctly, and thus cannot be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple code to check month, if number beyond limit it will reset and ask to type again

```js
function checkMonth(textbox){
  if(!(textbox.value > 0 && textbox.value <= 12 )){
    textbox.value = "";
    textbox.focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="month" min="1" max="12" onKeyUp="checkMonth(this)">
```